# Limpiar input en jsf después de actualizar datos

Tags: java, jsf

Tengo un modal que esta recuperando los datos del nombre de un registro, hasta allí todo bien hace la actualización del registro, pero sucede que cuando hace la modificación el campo donde se agregan los nuevos registros toma el valor de la modificación que recién se hizo y no se como hacer para que ese campo no tome ese valor.

**Aquí hago la actualización al registro**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Y aquí hace satisfactoriamente la actualización pero también el input donde se agrega una nueva categoría toma el valor**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CategoriaController**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

import sv.com.examplebootstrap.entities.Categoria;
import sv.com.examplebootstrap.repositories.CategoriaRepository;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CategoriaController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Categoria categoria;
    
    private List<Categoria> showCategoria;

    public Categoria getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }

    public void setCategoria(Categoria categoria) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.categoria = new Categoria();
    }
    
    @EJB
    private CategoriaRepository categoriaRepository;
    
    public void agregarCategoria() {
        categoriaRepository.agregarCategoria(categoria);
        System.out.println(categoria);
        this.categoria.setNombre("");
    }

    public List<Categoria> getShowCategoria() {
        this.showCategoria = categoriaRepository.mostrarCategoria();
        return showCategoria;
    }
    
    public void modificaCategoria() {
        categoriaRepository.modificarCategoria(categoria);
    }
    
    public void eliminarCategoria() {
        categoriaRepository.eliminarCategoria(categoria);
    }
    
}
```

**index.xhtml**

```
<div class="container">
        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>Tabla de categorias</h1>
                <h:form>
                    <h:inputText id="addNombre" a:placeholder="Nombre de producto" value="#{categoriaController.categoria.nombre}" />
                    <h:commandButton actionListener="#{categoriaController.agregarCategoria()}" value="Agregar" />
                </h:form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">

                <h:dataTable var="c" class="table table-striped" value="#{categoriaController.showCategoria}">
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Id</f:facet>
                        #{c.id}
                    </h:column>

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Nombre</f:facet>
                        #{c.nombre}
                    </h:column>

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Acciones</f:facet>
                        <h:commandButton value="Modificar" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="$('#modalModificar').modal('show');">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{c}" target="#{categoriaController.categoria}" />
                            <f:ajax execute="@this" render=":formModificar"/>
                        </h:commandButton >
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalModificar" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalModificarLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modificar</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <h:form id="formModificar">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h:inputText id="nombre" value="#{categoriaController.categoria.nombre}" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                        <h:commandButton class="btn btn-success" actionListener="#{categoriaController.modificaCategoria()}" value="Guardar" 
                        onclick="$('#modalModificar').modal('hide');"/>
                    </div>
                </h:form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo vi un poco rápido pero me parece que tu mayor problema está en que el input de agregar y el de modificar consumen el mismo value `{categoriaController.categoria.nombre}`. Es decir que si uno modifica el nombre de categoría (**setNombre()**) el otro campo cuando haga un **getNombre()** va a obtener este nuevo y ultimo valor. Seguramente cuando empieza la ejecución ese **getNombre()** no retorna nada por lo que se pone el valor del placeholder en el input de agregar (**"Nombre de producto"**)